# What is a correct overpass-turbo query for getting all streets in a city?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I want to get all streets in NYC using http://overpass-turbo.eu/. I tried this:

```
[out:json]; area[name = "New York"]; (node(area)[highway=street]; ); out;
```

However it returns

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.1009 5e627b63",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2019-11-13T19:26:03Z",
    "timestamp_areas_base": "2019-11-13T18:05:02Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [



  ]
}
```

No elements. However this query:

```
[out:json]; area[name = "New York"]; ( node(area)[amenity=cinema]; node(area)[highway=street]; ); out;
```

for getting streets *and* cinemas, works:

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.1009 5e627b63",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2019-11-13T19:29:02Z",
    "timestamp_areas_base": "2019-11-13T18:05:02Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 344994897,
  "lat": 41.7680892,
  "lon": -73.9291000,
  "tags": {
    "amenity": "cinema",
    "created_by": "Potlatch 0.10f",
    "name": "Roosevelt Theater"
  }
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 344996199,
  "lat": 41.7727941,
  "lon": -73.9292159,
  "tags": {
    "amenity": "cinema",
    "created_by": "Potlatch 0.10f",
    "name": "Hyde Park Drive-In"
  }
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 368043485,
  "lat": 40.7259416,
  "lon": -73.9973321,
  "tags": {
    "addr:state": "NY",
    "amenity": "cinema",
    "ele": "10",
    "gnis:county_name": "New York",
    "gnis:feature_id": "2082840",
    "gnis:import_uuid": "57871b70-0100-4405-bb30-88b2e001a944",
    "gnis:reviewed": "no",
    "name": "Angelika Film Center",
    "source": "USGS Geonames",
    "wikidata": "Q45104731"
  }
},
...
```

How should I modify the initial query to get the streets?

**EDIT**:

I tried

```
[out:json];
area[name = "New Hampshire"]->.a;          // Redirect result to ".a"
out body qt;
(
  way
    (area.a)                    // Use result from ".a"
    ["highway"="living_street"];
);
out body qt;
>;
out skel qt;
```

but it didn't select all of the streets, just several. And how should I specify that I mean a state by `New Hampshire`? I need all streets with postcodes (zip).

this doesn't display any streets at all:

```
[out:json];
area[name = "Acworth"]->.a;          // Redirect result to ".a"
out body qt;
(
  way
    (area.a)                    // Use result from ".a"
    ["highway"="living_street"];
);
out body qt;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Although it should at least display these: https://geographic.org/streetview/usa/nh/sullivan/acworth.html

Comment: @Cyril Oh, sorry, that's what I meant by the first query, that's the one that doesn't work.

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844414/what-is-a-correct-overpass-turbo-query-for-getting-all-streets-in-a-city

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to combine several highway=* queries into a single one.

```
[out:json];
area[name = "New York"];
(way(area)["highway"~"^(motorway|trunk|primary)$"];>;);
out;
```

Note: this query returns more than 40 MB worth of data.

NB: Be sure to review https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20531/overpass-ql-nodes-and-ways-in-area when using multiple query statements for the same area.

Comment: I've removed my incorrect post in favor of @mmd's.

Answer (score 0):

This Python script will query the Overpass API to get all cities in a US state. Since the API returns duplicates, the script removes them. Finally, the streets are sorted alphabetically and printed out.

```py
import requests

def query_overpass_api(query):
    # Overpass API endpoint.
    overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"

    params = {
        'data': query,
        'format': 'json'
    }

    response = requests.get(overpass_url, params=params)

    # If successful.
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        return None

def get_streets_in_city(city, state):
    overpass_query = """
        [out:json];

        area["ISO3166-1"="US"]->.us;
        area["admin_level"="4"]["name"="{state}"]->.state;
        area["admin_level"="8"]["name"="{city}"]->.city;
        way(area.us)(area.state)(area.city)[highway][name];
        out tags;
    """.format(city=city, state=state)

    result = query_overpass_api(overpass_query)

    if not result:
        print("Error querying Overpass API.")
        return None

    streets = {}

    for element in result["elements"]:
        highway = element["tags"]["highway"]
        name = element["tags"]["name"]
        streets[name] = highway

    streets = dict(sorted(streets.items()))

    return streets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example Overpass query to get all streets in Concord, NH.
    streets = get_streets_in_city("Concord", "New Hampshire")

    if streets:
        for street_name, street_type in streets.items():
            print(street_name + " - " + street_type)
```